# (JS/react-native) How can I solve this error for building react-native app for iOS

Tags: react-native

Hey guys I'm so new to JS and react-native as well. I was trying to solve this error but I couldn't get it at all! meh

This is what I struggled :

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-ble-plx (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-ble-plx")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
error Could not find the following native modules: RNCAsyncStorage, react-native-ble-plx. Did you forget to run "pod install" ?
info Found Xcode workspace "Sat008.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace Sat008.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Sat008 -destination id=61F7DB8A-467A-4027-95C3-B030C17EAA17")
...............
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Sat008.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Sat008.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Sat008 -destination id=61F7DB8A-467A-4027-95C3-B030C17EAA17

Prepare build
note: Using legacy build system
=== BUILD TARGET Sat008 OF PROJECT Sat008 WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
The file “Pods-Sat008.debug.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Users/hyunmincho/Documents/React-Native/SAT_008_DEV/Earthrise-Anders/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Sat008/Pods-Sat008.debug.xcconfig)

PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/hyunmincho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sat008-fynygwtjzergqceioiaqjhnwrfbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Sat008.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sat008.build/Script-D12BA90C2EB97176F46BC0FF.sh
    cd /Users/hyunmincho/Documents/React-Native/SAT_008_DEV/Earthrise-Anders/app/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/hyunmincho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sat008-fynygwtjzergqceioiaqjhnwrfbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Sat008.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sat008.build/Script-D12BA90C2EB97176F46BC0FF.sh
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/hyunmincho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sat008-fynygwtjzergqceioiaqjhnwrfbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Sat008.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sat008.build/Script-D12BA90C2EB97176F46BC0FF.sh
(1 failure)
```